# Has Richard Spencer called for a "peaceful ethnic cleansing"?

Tags: united-states, politics, quotes

There are many articles claiming that Richard Spencer called for a "peaceful ethnic cleansing".

However, [CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/12/06/politics/richard-spencer-interview-texas-am-speech/) says that Spencer denies this:

> He once called for a "peaceful ethnic cleansing," a claim he denied during the interview with CNN. But when asked how he would go about removing non-white from America, he had this to say:
>   "We have experienced this mass migration of people" into the United States, Spencer said. "Therefore they could go home, you can go home again. ... They came here peacefully. They could leave peacefully."

Calling for an ethnic cleansing would match Spencers political views, and the answer to CNN seems to confirm that this is a policy he supports. But I was unable to find the source for that specific quote. The closest I could find was [this](http://www.radixjournal.com/journal/2016/9/28/facing-the-future-as-a-minority):

> Today, in the public imagination, “ethnic-cleansing” has been associated with civil war and mass murder (understandably so).  But this need not be the case.  1919 is a real example of successful ethnic redistribution—done by fiat, we should remember, but done peacefully.

However, most articles surround the phrase with quotes, so I am assuming that it is a direct quote.

Has Richard Spencer called for a "peaceful ethnic cleansing" in those words?

Comment: Non-white "came here peacefully"?  Slavery was peaceful now?  Do we really want to take these kind of claims seriously?

Comment: Relevant: https://twitter.com/RichardBSpencer/status/765429814480089088

Comment: Relevant: http://www.npiamerica.org/the-national-policy-institute/blog/facing-the-future-as-a-minority

Comment: @gerrit The statements by Spencer are obviously ridiculous (and it seems to me that 'peacefully' is only added for propaganda purposes, because calling for forceful ethnic cleansing isn't politically helpful right now). Still, the claim in question is if some news outlet put their paraphrased words in quotes, or if Spencer actually said it like this (and what the context was).

Comment: Related question on Politics.SE: [How would Richard Spencer execute a 'peaceful ethnic cleansing' if he gets elected?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/16630/2130)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes he did.

In a (**NSFW**)[speech that he delivered](http://www.npiamerica.org/the-national-policy-institute/blog/facing-the-future-as-a-minority) at the 2013 American Renaissance conference, he said:

> Today, in the public imagination, “**ethnic-cleansing**” has been associated with civil war and mass murder (understandably so).  But this need not be the case.  1919 is a real example of successful ethnic redistribution—done by fiat, we should remember, but done **peacefully**.

He has also admitted in a [tweet](https://twitter.com/RichardBSpencer/status/765429814480089088) that he talked about "peaceful ethnic cleansing", linking to the same speech. A screen grab of the tweet:

[image: Btw, here's the speech in which I mention "peaceful ethnic cleansing." I reference Woodrow Wilson.]

Most sources online that cite Spencer as supporting peaceful ethnic cleansing source it to the [Southern Poverty Law Center](https://www.splcenter.org/fighting-hate/extremist-files/individual/richard-bertrand-spencer-0) which cites the same speech:

> In an address at white supremacist Jared Taylor’s 2013 American Renaissance conference, Spencer called for “peaceful ethnic cleansing.” As an example of how this could be accomplished, he cited the 1919 Paris Peace Conference, where new national boundaries were formed at the end of World War I. “Today, in the public imagination, ‘ethnic cleansing’ has been associated with civil war and mass murder (understandably so),” Spencer said. “But this need not be the case. 1919 is a real example of successful ethnic redistribution—done by fiat, we should remember, but done peacefully.”

Comment: So the answer to the question - is this a direct quote - would be no? But Spencer *did* talk positively about ethnic cleansing, and also said that it doesn't necessarily have to be violent, and that there is one example in the past which was done peacefully? If the SPLC is the original source, this seems to be the case (I'll accept if nobody else finds more info).(btw, I don't think Spencers tweet says much; It could be interpreted as quoting news outlets of which Spencer thinks they misquoted him; given that the link *doesn't* contain the exact words, it seems more like a denial of the quote)

Comment: @tim, I took the tweet at face value, but now that you mention it, it could be interpreted that as him showing he was misquoted. In any case, following sources from several articles led me to either the SPLC directly, or to other sources quoting them, and the SPLC base their findings on the 2013 speech. I didn't read the speech in its entirety (there is a limit to what I'm willing to do), but skimped it using find and several related keywords.

Comment: Yeah, real peaceful, especially when they didn't bother asking the natives how they felt about more or less arbitrarily being assigned "nations" based on their physical location. And I feel anyone who brings up 1919 as an example of anything should be required to admit that the atrociously offensive "treaty of Versailles" contributed hugely to the conditions that helped put the Nazis in power in Germany.

Comment: @Shadur, I don't think that in Spencer's view "helped put the Nazis in power" is a bad thing.